# Why Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why I remove code in line 14($this->close();), it don't have error but i don't remove it then it warning mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli. It is at the end construct ???
My error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8V9u.png)
My code:

```
<?php

class Display extends Awebarts
{
    private $conn;
    private $tablename;

    public function __construct($tablename)
    {

        $this->tablename = $tablename;

        $this->connectToDb();
        $this->conn = $this->getConn();
        // insert the data into the table
        $this->getData();

        $this->close();
    }

    function getData()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
        if(!$sql = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query)) {
            throw new Exception("Error: Can not excute the query.");
        } else {
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            while($num > 0) {
                //var_dump($data);
                $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
                $num--;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

class Awebarts
{
    private $cxn;
    private $conn;

    function connectToDb()
    {
        include "models/Database.php";
        $vars = "include/vars.php";
        $this->cxn = new Database($vars);
        $this->conn = $this->cxn->getConn();
    }

    function getConn()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    function close()
    {
        $this->cxn->close();
    }
}

class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $conn;

    function __construct($filename)
    {
        if(is_file($filename)) {
            include $filename;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->connect();
        $this->selectData();
    }

    function getConn()
    {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        // connect to the sercer
        if(!mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)) {
            throw new Exception("Error: not connected to the server");
        } else {
            $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }

    private function selectData()
    {
        if(!mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->database)) {
            throw new Exception("Error: No database");
        }
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: So there's an issue in `close`? How about showing us that?

Comment: Also please provide the full error message.

Comment: Without the full error, anything is just a guess, but try putting braces `{}` around `$this->tablename` in your query.

Comment: Try this. `$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->tablename." ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";`

Comment: I tried  $query='SELECT * FROM "$this->tablename" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 '; it error: Can not excute the query  and   $query="SELECT * FROM ``main_settings`` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1" ; it error: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: Hopefully `$this->tablename` isn't a user-supplied value? Or if it is, then hopefully you've sanitised to so it can only be valid a table name? Otherwise you've got a massive SQL injection attack right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the connection is closed when you call `getData()` after you have created the `Display` object.

The `getData()` call in your constructor doesn't make any sense, because you don't use/save the return value. So when then constructor is executed you open a connection, send a select query (which return value you don't save) and then close the connection. After that a `getData()` call results in your error message.

You can either save the result of your `getData()` call from the constructor in a private field and access it later or remove the `getData()` and `$this->close();` call from the constructor and call them from outside.

Comment: I fix error by add destructor(){$this->close()} in class display

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform method Database::connect like this:

```
private function connect()
        {
            // connect to the sercer
            if(!$connect = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)) {
                throw new Exception("Error: not connected to the server");
            }
            $this->conn = $connect;
            return $this->conn;
        }
```